# Conditional loop

Tags: c#

```
        static bool BoxDiscovery(h) {
            ...
            //I've acquired bmp by this point in the ellipses above 

            for (int v = 211; v < 661; v++) {
                Color c = bmp.GetPixel(h, v);
                if (c.R > 221 && c.G < 153)
                //if c.r > 221 && c.G < 153 get me out of this crazy
                //  thing Jane and return true, else false without the
                //  compiler throwing an 'Unreachable code detected'. 
                //  Use break or anything you want.
                ...
                }
            }
        }
```

I'm feeling especially stupid today.

Comment: Put the `return true` inside and `return false` outside...?

Comment: Have you tried just `if (...) return true; else return false`. The only problem that you'll always exit from the function on the first step with v == 211. If you want to return false if `(c.R > 221 && c.G < 153)` never happened just do `if (...) return true` and add `return false` after your loop.

Comment: Do you want to return `true` if *any* pixel is outside those values, and `false` if all pixels are inside them? Or do you want to return `false` if *any* pixel is inside those values and `true` if all pixels are outside them? Or do you just want to return `true`/`false` based on the first pixel in the image?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
static bool BoxDiscovery(h) 
{
    for (int v = 211; v < 661; v++) 
    {
        Color c = bmp.GetPixel(h, v);
        if (c.R > 221 && c.G < 153)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    // Make sure you provide a default value here
    // If we reach this point your condition hasn't been 
    // satisfied meaning that no box has been found
    // so you can safely return false
    return false;
}
```