# php oop - each class different file? import package? etc

Tags: php, oop

I am used to working in languages such as `C#`/`Java`/`Python` where each class would have its own file, and for a **class** to see other classes, you would **import** the package containing those classes. How does this work in `php`? The documentation shows you how to create classes, but I don't understand how it all fits together in a `php` context. I know of the include statement, which just sticks the files together basically.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Import package or autoloading for PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/616231/import-package-or-autoloading-for-php)

Comment: *(tipp)* search for autoloading and code conventions in PHP

Comment: Personally, I find it very sensible to have each class in its own file... but use an autoloader rather than java's import

Comment: @middaparka: I was the subject of a completely off-topic (although short-lived) discussion just the other day.

Comment: @middaparka: The comment that started it was removed by flagging, but contextual remnants can be found in meagar's reply [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4717369/conditional-loop).

Comment: Check out psr-4 autoloading using Composer - https://getcomposer.org/ .  It will greatly help with organization, especially in the realm of namespacing.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use __autoload

```
function __autoload($class_name) {
    include 'classes/'.$class_name . '.php';
}
```

So place every single class in its own file in the classes folder. When you want to use that class it will include it. More info: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php

**Update:** When I answered this it was fully valid. Now it still works, but keep in mind PHP.net since then says this:

> [spl_autoload_register()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php) provides a more flexible alternative for
>   autoloading classes. For this reason, using __autoload() is
>   discouraged and may be deprecated or removed in the future.

Comment: Also take a look at: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php

Answer (score 5):

The easiest way:

- define your classes in "classes" directory
- init application like shown below
- name class filenames as their lowercase class name with .php suffix (MyClass => classes/myclass.php)

Init code:

```
set_include_path ( "./classes" );
spl_autoload_register ();

//class is automatically loaded from ./classes/myclass.php
$object_instance = new MyClass ();
```

Answer (score 3):

As of PHP 5.3.0 , it is recommended that you use the spl_autoload_register() function because __autoload() is said to be deprecated some time in the future.

An easy way to use this function:

1) Place each class file into the 'classes' folder

2) Run an anonymous function inside spl_autoload_register() which specifies your class folder:

```
spl_autoload_register(function ($class) {
    include 'classes/' . $class . '.php';
});
```

Now when you try to use a class that is not defined in your code yet, it will check that class folder one last time before giving you an error.

Comment: This is cool but this is best used when you want your own autoloader with its own name as described in Example #1 here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php In this case __autoload is enough.

Answer (score 1):

Imagine you have been making your object in PHP in a file called myObject.php

```
<?php

  class myObject
  {
    public function __construct()
    {
      echo "Hello, World";
    }
  }

?>
```

And in another file, you would like to use the object (let's call this myfile.php). You would have to include your object - like this:

```
<?php

  include("myObject.php");

  $intance = new myObject();

?>
```

Quite simple.

Comment: Until you need to manage a list of includes that's longer than your code.

Comment: @Mchl: Oh that's easy, place the includes in their own include file and include it :P

Answer (score 0):

In PHP you can do it in various ways, compiler does not limit you.

You can have 1 class in 1 file, 5 classes in 1 file, 1 class across several files using includes...

But usually it's still 1 class in 1 files, and if you have many tiny ones - you can have them in 1 folder too.

When doing 1 class in 1 file with the same name you can set up class autoload so that you don't need to write your includes.

Comment: You can NOT have a class split over multiple files. See here for example:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1957732/can-i-include-code-into-a-php-class/1957830#1957830